# Проблема с установкой на хост

Tags: python, django

При подключении по SSH логинюсь в аккаунт и пытаюсь активировать виртуальное окружение командой source /home/xn80aue1/virtualenv/app/3.10/bin/activate && cd /home/xn80aue1/app  которая выдается на хостинге. Помогите как решить данную проблему. Я понимаю что такой команды нет, но нужно найти альтернативу

[image: Команда, предлагаемая на хостинге][image: Консоль хостинга по SSH подключению]

Comment: Вы не по SSH подключаетесь, а по SFTP. Проверьте параметры подключения

Comment: тем не менее, все команды типа cd работают, к серверу подключаюсь. Нужна лишь альтернатива команде sourse или как запустить файл activate